# Iterating items in a list and comparing to that same list

Tags: c#

Trying to iterate through a csv and find records where if there is a record within the current list of records that shares the same RelatedOrder, group all records with the same RelatedOrder together and from those, return the record with the greatest RecordID.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm pretty new.

My Class:

```
namespace Application
{
    class DataRecord
    {
        public String RecordID { get; set; }
        public String RelatedOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Path:");
            var filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
                {
                var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
                IEnumerable<DataRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>();
                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    // If there is a record within the current list of records that shares the same 
                    // RelatedOrder, group all records with the same RelatedOrder and return the record
                    // with the greatest RecordID

                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
var recordsWithHighestRecordsByRelatedOrder = 
 reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>()
       .GroupBy(dr => dr.RelatedOrder)
       .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.RecordID).First())
```

- First you group all your records by the relatedOrder
- This gives you a list of groups (each group has a Key and is a list or DataRecord)
- Of that list of lists you select the first item in each list with the highest RecordId

NOTE: take care when comparing and sorting strings. I suppose your intention is to order the RecordId numerically, not alphabetically. It'd be better to modify your class to the following:

```
class DataRecord
{
    public int RecordID { get; set; } // Make this an int
    public String RelatedOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver, mate.